# Getting around circular reference in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, circular-dependency

I have a google docs spreadsheet with two columns: A and B.
Values of B are just values from A in a different format, and I have a formula in the B column that does the conversion.
Sometimes I do not have the values in A format but I have them in B format. I would like to automatically get the values in A format in the A column by adding the formula that does the reverse conversion in the A column. This, of course, generates a circular reference. Is there a way to get around it?

Comment: This question probably belongs on webapps.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From this week, Google Sheets has announced support for exactly this feature. You can now limit the number of iterations for circular references in the spreadsheets settings :-)

Answer (score 16):

On the top menu of a google spreadsheet do the following:

File > Spreadsheet settings

Choose the "Calculation" tab, and change "Iterative calculation" to ON.

Enjoy :D.

PD: I know that this post is too old, but just some days ago I needed a solution to this, and I couldn´t find any.

[image]

Comment: It doesn't matter that it's too old; the answer you provided was not here, and it shows the exact solution I was looking for. This indeed should be the accepted answer for this post. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

In excel you can set it to allow circular dependencies and limit the number of iterations they run (usually 1 is the desired result).

I've looked and nothing like that exists in sheets.

Comment: Just ran into this. Something like this in sheets would be amazin

Comment: The "usually 1 is the desired result" just got me out of my hours-long spinning-my-wheels frustration. I for some reason had 2 in there? 1 does the trick! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I know that this post is pretty old, but I saw it while looking to see the applications of a thing.

In sheets, you can use `importrange` to reference the same sheet and call the desired range. For instance, you can put a formula in `B1` that is `=A1+1` and in `A1` use the formula `=importrange(<THIS SHEET ID>,"B1")+1`.

You may need to initially put the formula in `A2` and then move it up to `A1`, but it should work.

Doing something like this essentially makes a second counter, which is neat I guess?

Answer (score 0):

Solved with a script that implements the following algorithm

```
for each row{
   if (A != "" && B == "")
    B = conversionFromA(A);
   if (A == "" && B != "")
    A = conversionFrom(B);}
```

of course it has it's downsides, (you have to call the script each time you enter new data), but it's the best solution I found

Answer (score 0):

I would add two more columns: data source and data format. Then, the formula in column A would take a value from data source either as is (if the format matches) or converted (if format doesn't match). Same for column B.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of referencing your co-dependent formula cells, use other cells to hold your actual (non-formulaic) data and use the formula cells to show your results.

Comment: This answer is outdated. Check Henrik Soderlund for the correct answer.