# Google Spreadsheet Circular Dependency

Tags: google-sheets, circular-dependency

I need help to avoid circular dependency using Google Spreadsheets. I am building a spreadsheet for a rotating shift worker to search for a date, and then see what shift they are working that day, or if they are off that day. Since I am basically putting a  start date in Column A2 and then making B2 = A2 +5 (for the 5 Days Shift) then having C2 = B2 +4 (for the 4 days off) and so on.... I run into circular dependency issues, I have found many ways around this but no ways to have the spreadsheet continue to update itself as the old dates(dates that have passed) are deleted. 
[this my spreadsheet so far](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14qKNOtXKPhm8e3BxvA_MGQr_NOMuEK3Wu_dzv5OHLBk/edit?usp=sharing)

I have a script editor that I am trying to use to update my spreadsheet when the date in 'Copy of Shift B' H3 is is less than today's date(B2). When I test this that is when the whole spreadsheet breaks with #REF circular dependency.

Comment: At this time there are #VALUE! errors in 'Copy of Shift B'!A3:M58 because A2 is text instead a number/date

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting around circular reference in Google Spreadsheet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14383613/getting-around-circular-reference-in-google-spreadsheet)

Answer (score 2):

You can change settings for Iterative calculation

- File > Spreadsheet Settings > Calculation > Iterative calculation > off→on